How to solve CORS error while using Axios?
I want to make a request to 3rd party API for some data. While using axios for request I am getting CORS error, while the requests are success while using Fetch API.
Is there something I need to tweak in my axios config so it allows cross domain requests?
Note: I can't do changes on server side as it is 3rd party API
P.S. I recognized some differences in network tab usign axios and fetch. Axios first sends preflight request with options method (which returns bad request) and then actual get method which returns CORS error. While fetch has only 1 request with get method which is success
